# Uncaught RuntimeException: Callable does not exist

Tags: php, slim

I am trying a simple Slim application as shown below.

`index.php`

```php
<?php
use Slim\Factory\AppFactory;

require './vendor/autoload.php';

$app = AppFactory::create();

$app->get('/', [TestController::class, 'showBlank']);

$app->run();
```

And below is the `TestController.php`.

```php
<?php
use \Psr\Container\ContainerInterface;
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface;
use Slim\Http\Interfaces\ResponseInterface;

class TestController
{
    protected $c;

    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $c)
    {
        $this->c = $c;
    }

    public function showBlank(ServerRequestInterface $request, ResponseInterface $response, array $args): ResponseInterface
    {
        return $response;
    }

}
```

Below is the project structure.

```bash
C:\laragon\www\chum>ls
composer.json  composer.lock  index.php  TestController.php  vendor
```

Since I am trying `slim` for first time, I am keep the example to very minimal and so the `composer.json` file.

```json
{
  "require": {
    "slim/slim": "^4.11",
    "slim/psr7": "^1.6",
    "slim/twig-view": "^3.3",
    "slim/http": "^1.3"
  }
}
```

Given these, I am getting the below exceptio when I try to access the root page(`\`).

```
Fatal error: Uncaught RuntimeException: Callable TestController::showBlank() does not exist in C:\laragon\www\chum\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\CallableResolver.php:138 

Stack trace: 
#0 C:\laragon\www\chum\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\CallableResolver.php(90): Slim\CallableResolver->resolveSlimNotation('TestController:...') 
#1 C:\laragon\www\chum\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\CallableResolver.php(63): Slim\CallableResolver->resolveByPredicate('TestController:...', Array, 'handle') 
#2 C:\laragon\www\chum\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\Routing\Route.php(340): Slim\CallableResolver->resolveRoute(Array) 
#3 C:\laragon\www\chum\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\MiddlewareDispatcher.php(65): Slim\Routing\Route->handle(Object(Slim\Http\ServerRequest)) 
#4 C:\laragon\www\chum\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\MiddlewareDispatcher.php(65): Slim\MiddlewareDispatcher->handle(Object(Slim\Http\ServerRequest)) 
#5 C:\laragon\www\chum\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\Routing\Route.php(315): Slim\MiddlewareDispatcher->handle(Object(Slim\Http\ServerRequest)) 
#6 C:\laragon\www\chum\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\Routing\RouteRunner.php(68): Slim\Routing\Route->run(Object(Slim\Http\ServerRequest)) 
#7 C:\laragon\www\chum\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\MiddlewareDispatcher.php(65): Slim\Routing\RouteRunner->handle(Object(Slim\Http\ServerRequest)) 
#8 C:\laragon\www\chum\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\App.php(199): Slim\MiddlewareDispatcher->handle(Object(Slim\Http\ServerRequest)) 
#9 C:\laragon\www\chum\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\App.php(183): Slim\App->handle(Object(Slim\Http\ServerRequest)) 
#10 C:\laragon\www\chum\index.php(56): Slim\App->run() #11 {main} thrown in C:\laragon\www\chum\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\CallableResolver.php on line 138
```

Comment: Have you set up `composer.json` to instruct PHP to find your classes?

Comment: I am in assumption that since all my classes are in same directory, namespaces are not required to try a simple application. Please correct me if I am wrong.. How should my composer.json file be configured for the given project structure?

Comment: Composer only loads what's defined in the [`autoload` section](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading). It won't traverse your entire codebase looking for classes. You don't _need_ to use namespaces, it's just the easy way. You can use `classmap` if you prefer.

Comment: And further, _PHP_ won't hunt for files either unless you instruct it to, usually by [`spl_autoload_register`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php), however composer can make this easier for you.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks `Alvaro` for the great tips in comments, I was able to solve it with some further help from Google based on that.

I was under assumption flat project structure does not need namespaces to be configured. But I was wrong.

I did the below updates to `composer.json` file and ran `composer dump-autoload -o`.

```
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "App\\": ""
    }
  },
```